# Store all possible substring in String []

Tags: java, string, substring

I want to store all possible substring in `String []`. I tried this but got an error:

```
public void sub(String word){                                                                                        
    String [] Str=new String[100];                                                                            
    int n=0;                                                                                                                                  
    for (int from = 0; from < word.length(); from++) {                                  
        for (int to = from + 1; to <= word.length(); to++) {             
            str[n]=word.substring(from, to);            
            n++;            
            System.out.println(str[n]);           
        }            
    }          
}
```

What is solution?

Comment: When you were typing your question, there was a bit orange box next to it titled **How to Format**. Worth a read. There was also a toolbar across the top making formatting, marking up code, etc., easy, and a preview area underneath showing you exactly what your question would look like when posted. For your next question, please use these tools. (Also, indent your code.) I've corrected things for you this time.

Comment: Ok i see. error is: cannot find symbol, variable str, loction: class substring

Comment: You write your variable `Str` and address it as `str`. Uppercase first, lowercase second. -> use `str` always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> error is: cannot find symbol, variable str, loction: class substring

Well, that fairly clearly tells you what the error is: You haven't declared `str`. You *have* declared `Str`, but Java's identifiers are case sensitive, `str` and `Str` are not the same identifier.

So change

```
String [] Str=new String[100];
```

to

```
String [] str=new String[100];
//        ^--- lower case
```

---

Before, when you hadn't said what the error was, there were a couple of other things [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) and I (amongst others) noticed:

You have a sequence issue here:

```
str[n]=word.substring(from, to);            
n++;            
System.out.println(str[n]);
```

...since you're incrementing `n` before outputting the string, you're always going to output `null`. Just moving the increment fixes that:

```
str[n]=word.substring(from, to);            
System.out.println(str[n]); 
n++;
```

Another possible problem can occur for longer words, where number of substrings can be more then 100. In that case you should avoid creating fixed size array, but try using dynamic size collection like `List`

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To put or read elements here just use `str.add(substring)` and `str.get(index)`.

Comment: tnx. but it print just a, al, l.

Comment: @Pshemo Now it works fine. tnx all.

Comment: now i have String [] wordsArray and i want to find nubmer of wordsArray[i] is substring in other wordsArray. any solution?

Comment: @user3359479 This is separate question so create separate post for it. Also don't forget to include your code attempts to solve it.